# Correct approach to statistical analysis of voting results

Tags: correlation, discrete-data

Consider data consisting of voting results. Votes can be either individual votes of jury members or aggregated votes by certain communities (professional of geographical). In the end there is a set of data where each row has three fields: Voter, Candidate (the one who collects votes) and Place (or rank, voters put candidates on different places). There are several competitions, so candidates are measured multiple times.

Now we want ot analyze if some voters are biased, e.g. if they keep on giving some candidates certain places no matter if those candidates deserve it. I am not really sure what's the proper way of achieving this. Here is what I am trying to figure out:

1. In case votes are collected from communities, voting results are based on raw data of different sizes: one community can have 100K members while the other one has only 1000. Can we still assume that "places" represent ordinal data, not categorical?
2. What is the recommended technique to evaluate if a voter is biased? I can think of a simple measurement: an average difference between a candidate's place and the place he is given by a certain voter. The more the difference, the more the candidate is overrated by this voter. But I am not sure this is right thing to do because with such approach a single very low mark can balance multiple overrated high marks.
3. I've read about chi-square and Fisher's tests but not sure if it's applicable here. AFAIK they are applicable to categorical data.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by
Place (voters put candidates on different places

Comment: Place is a some kind of rank, i.e. a voter puts one candidate on  a first place, some other candidate on a second place etc.

Comment: Do you have any reference or any measure on true votes? How are you measuring candidate deservedness

Comment: The only way to measure candidate "deservedness" is to compare his resulting place (assuming the number of voters is big enough to outvote biased votes) with the place given by a given voter. I.e. if candidate's is on 5th place, than the voter who put him on the 1st place is less fair than those who put him on 4th place. If a voter always puts some candidate higher than his resulting place, then such voter is biased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a **"Naive Bayes classifier"** ( see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier ) is the simple answer to your question.

You can train your implementation with "unbiased" positive and negative votes, and then run checks on future votes to see how "reliable" they are, giving them the appropriate vote-weight.

In short: such a naive Bayes classifier allows you to find out how "probable" a vote/rating is; which is - if I understand you correctly - exactly what you are looking for.

The fun thing about a naive Bayes classifier is that you can make your implementation learn on and get better with each vote/rating it receives. Think: machine learns by itself, after you gave it some initial learning aid.

And if you're not sure if something like that actually works... yes it does. The IMDB uses exactly the same method to process their ratings and to detect biased or spammy votes/ratings ( see: https://resume.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?votes ).

Oh, and I use naive Bayes classifiers too whenever I implement rating, voting and/or comment systems. But then again, who am I compared to the well-known IMDB? ;)

**UPDATE**

Look what I found: a similar question with some answers that might be useful for you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134504/what-is-the-best-algorithm-to-calculate-the-most-scored-item

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Looks like this what I am looking for, IMDB is very similar to my case. Also thanks for StackOverflow link, it presents good practical approach to my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help. ;)